# How to speed up the tableview's performance with many images?

Tags: ios, performance, uitableview, caching, uiimage

I've developing an iPad app.And I have a uitableview, in which every cell has about four to five images.And almost four to five cells on screen.

So there are about 20~30 images on screen.

The images are not very large , perhaps 200*200.(already some kind of thunbnail)

All the images are local resource.

The problem is that when first scroll down the tableview, it needs to load new cells and of course the images in the cells. This makes the UI become laggy.

But when you scroll back up ,it's very smooth. I know this is because UIImage class will cache some images.when scroll back up, the images are cached, so it's smooth.

So my question is how to deal with this?

1.Make as small thumbnail as possible?

2.Pre-load some image?(How?)

3.Use custom cache?(also how?)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend fetching the images with GCD. I would also subclass the `UITableViewCell` and in it's `drawRect:` draw all pictures on the view's layer. That will increase your performance dramatically.

Comment: Actually in my experience UIImageViews is best for drawing images in a tableview, especially when they're thumbnails. I read somewhere that UIImageView uses the GPU where as drawRect (i.e. CoreGraphics) uses the CPU.

Comment: that's correct, but merging four images down to one, that's also drawn on the views layer, is a performance boost. I'm building something similar just now and I've found `CGContextDrawImage()` more faster than `[imageView.layer renderInContext:]`. But this is only if you want to draw all images in the same layer.

Comment: Can someone provide example code for this?

Comment: @ScottyBlades the post is from 2012, this should not be necessary anymore. Look into asynchronous loading if you experience stuttering in lists.

Answer (score 1):

If there is not so much images in the table - you can precache by loading them, when the view is created. Otherwise use more generic approach with async loading in background thread.

Comment: async loading would be better approach. I am using that in my app and its perfectly smooth .

Comment: I totally agree, however sometimes simplest thing which does the job could be the best )